# Why show this error,",Uncaught ReferenceError: c3 is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, c3.js

I have created one calculator in that calculator i have use pie chart to show data  dynamically,but chart throw error.The code is given below,

**custom.min.js** in this js file i have usen c3 chart,

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ["Interest Payable", 3900519],
            ["Principal", 3e6]
        ],
        type: "pie"
    },
    axis: { x: { label: "Sepal.Width" }, y: { label: "Petal.Width" } },
    legend: { show: !1 },
    tooltip: { format: { title: function(t) { return "" }, value: function(t, e, n) { return t } }, contents: tooltip_contents }
});
```

I have usen this plugin to done this **:** **c3.min.js,c3_renderers.min.js,d3.min.js,d3.v3.min.js,pivot.min.js.**

I have downloaded this plugin and put inside the asset folder and I am call this js file by scriptloaderService, and this scriptloaderService imported inside component.

**DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService** this is scriptloaderServise code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface Scripts {
  name: string;
  src: string;
}

export const ScriptStore: Scripts[] = [
  { name: 'd3.v3.min.js', src: './assets/Scripts/d3.v3.min.js' },
  { name: 'd3.min.js', src: './assets/Scripts/d3.min.js'},
  { name: 'c3.min.js', src: './assets/Scripts/c3.min.js' },
  { name: 'custom.min.js', src: './assets/Scripts/custom.min.js' },
];

declare var document: any;

@Injectable()
export class DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService {


  private scripts: any = {};

  constructor() {
    ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
      this.scripts[script.name] = {
        loaded: false,
        src: script.src
      };
    });
  }

  load(...scripts: string[]) {
    const promises: any[] = [];
    scripts.forEach((script) => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }

  loadScript(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.scripts[name].loaded) {
        //load script
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
        if (script.readyState) {  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                    resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = () => {
                this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
            };
        }
        script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded'});
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      } else {
        resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already Loaded' });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**CalcyComponent** this is component in which service and JS file was called to show pie chart.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService } from '../../../ScriptLoaderService/dynamic-script-loader-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calcy',
  templateUrl: './calcy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calcy.component.css']
})
export class CalcyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private dynamicScriptLoader:DynamicScriptLoaderServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScripts();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() { }

  loadScripts() {
    // You can load multiple scripts by just providing the key as argument into load method of the service
    this.dynamicScriptLoader.load(
    'd3.v3.min.js','d3.min.js','c3.min.js','custom.min.js',).then(data => {
      // Script Loaded Successfully
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

**calcy.component.html** this is template where chart should be show, I have given small code of that.

```
<div class="abc">
    <div id="chart" class="chart" style="width: 320px; height: 285px;"></div>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div title="" style="width: 454px;
                height: 319px;">
            <!-- <div id="Graph"></div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Main error shown by browser is this. "Uncaught ReferenceError: c3 is not defined"

***any one can help in this code????***

Comment: Can you check if the scripts are loaded at the moment that the c3.generate is executed?